# CSV file downloaded from Kaggle shows filter and other options in my data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have downloaded a CSV file from Kaggle and it shows filter, pagination, and other options. I want to know why it comes and how to remove it.

[image]

I want to remove all options that are showing in my data frame.

[image]

Comment: (1) You shared two of the same picture. (2) Please share data as text, not images. (3) What is the "it" when you say, "why _it_ comes"? Please be more descriptive.